# Reverse engineering cumulative to daily data?

Tags: r, diff, cumsum, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe for which I have date data and cumulative counts.
I am trying to do a *reverse of cumsum* to get the daily counts **but** also getting the counts per group.
I am trying to go from dataframe A to dataframe B.
I am using R and `tidyr`.

Here is the code :

```
df <- data.frame(cum_count = c(5, 14, 50, 5, 14, 50),
                 state = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "NY", "NY", "NY"),
                 Year = c(2012:2014, 2012:2014))
```

```
Dataframe A
  cum_count   state Year
1         5 Alabama 2012
2        14 Alabama 2013
3        50 Alabama 2014
4         5      NY 2012
5        14      NY 2013
6        50      NY 2014
```

```
Dataframe B
  cum_count   state Year
1         5 Alabama 2012
2         9 Alabama 2013
3        36 Alabama 2014
4         5      NY 2012
5         9      NY 2013
6        36      NY 2014
```

I have tried using the diff function :

```
df <- df %>%group_by(state)%>%
      mutate(daily_count = diff(cum_count))
```

But I get

> Error: Column `daily_count` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

Let me know what you think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `diff`, e.g.,

```
df <- df %>%group_by(state)%>%
  mutate(daily_count = c(cum_count[1],diff(cum_count)))
```

such that

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   state [2]
  cum_count state    Year daily_count
      <dbl> <chr>   <int>       <dbl>
1         5 Alabama  2012           5
2        14 Alabama  2013           9
3        50 Alabama  2014          36
4         5 NY       2012           5
5        14 NY       2013           9
6        50 NY       2014          36
```

---

Here is a base R option via `ave`

```
df <- within(df,daily_count <- ave(cum_count,state,FUN = function(x) c(x[1],diff(x))))
```

such that

```
> df
  cum_count   state Year daily_count
1         5 Alabama 2012           5
2        14 Alabama 2013           9
3        50 Alabama 2014          36
4         5      NY 2012           5
5        14      NY 2013           9
6        50      NY 2014          36
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding! Your solution works indeed. But I updated the problem to my dataset more specifically and added the challenge of doing so per group. Here by state. In that case scenario, it does not work unfortunately. Do you think you can find a way around it?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. Works like marvel!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(df)[ , daily_count:= (cum_count - shift(cum_count, type="lag",n = 1)), by="state"][is.na(daily_count), daily_count:=cum_count,]
```

that can be split into two steps:

1. Create counts as difference between current value and from previous row

`setDT(df)[ , daily_count:= (cum_count - shift(cum_count, type="lag",n = 1)), by="state"]`

2. Fill up NAs (first rows for each state) with cum_count value.

`df[is.na(daily_count), daily_count:=cum_count,]`

Output:

```
   cum_count   state Year daily_count
1:         5 Alabama 2012           5
2:        14 Alabama 2013           9
3:        50 Alabama 2014          36
4:         5      NY 2012           5
5:        14      NY 2013           9
6:        50      NY 2014          36
```